# Assign world file to many tiff obtained using a grid/reticulate

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I've many .tiff exported on the base of a grid/reticulate, and now I need to make them georeferenced.

There is an automatic method that allow this using the coordinates of the vertexes provided from the reticulate?

Or other solution?

Comment: Do you mean 'graticule' as opposed to 'reticulate'? If the tiffs were exported from GIS software shouldn't they already be georeferenced? Was there just a grid in an original, unreferenced image you sliced it up by? What software, version, license level, extensions, are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had some damaged GeoTiff files.  What happened is that a person ran the GeoTiff through Photoshop.  Photoshop and most other drawing problems ignore the GeoTiff part of the tiff file and wind up bashing the spatial information in the header.

You do not say what tools you have available.  What I did to fix the problem was to use the coordinates that I have--sounds like you have these by **grid/reticulate** comment above--and then create a .vrt file in the same directory as the .tiff file. [The GDAL Virtual Format Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) explains how this can be done.  I then referenced the .vrt file.  The .vrt file points to the .tiff file.  .vrt files are a wonderful idea because they are just text xml files.  Again depending on your tools, you may want to use the gdal/gdalwarp tools to convert the .vrt file into a real GeoTiff so that you have broader tool support.

Comment: Been there, done that Greg... a handy hint for you (and others of course) is GeoTiff Examiner ftp://priede.bf.lu.lv/pub/TIS/failu_formaati/GeoTIFF/geotiffe.HTM - export the world file then edit in Photoshop, after editing open again and copy the values from the world file. In the case where the originals are available export the world file from those, move to the same location as the edited files and then import the world files using the utility; if not, then a python or similar script is called for provided you can accurately predict where the hook points will fall.